# no such file or directory when downloading a file from firebase cloud storage using http cloud cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, filesystems, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I wrote a .txt file in firebase cloud storage and i want to download that .txt file and sending it to another server validation. I tried so many ways to download that file but i am getting an error like

```
"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/vijayasrivuddanti/Downloads/download.txt'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Users/vijayasrivuddanti/Downloads/download.txt'"
```

This is the code i tried :

```
function writetofile(){
const storage = new Storage();
const  bucket = storage.bucket('deyapay-192704.appspot.com'); 
console.log("date",Date.now());
var datetime = new Date();
console.log("iso", new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10));
const file = bucket.file(new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)+".txt"); // It create the file in the bucket in ascii format and save as today date format.
const a = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)+".ascii"
console.log("filename",a);
var storageRef = admin.storage().bucket();
const uploadStream = file.createWriteStream();
uploadStream.on('error', function(err) {
console.log("write err",err);
});
finalnachaformat.forEach(function(v) { // It takes the each value in 
                                       finalnachaformat in every loop.
    console.log("v",v)
    console.log("gii");
    uploadStream.write(v+ '\n'); // and write data into file.
    console.log("looping function",v);   
}) 
 console.log("successfully uploaded")
uploadStream.end();// writing end
//-
// Download a file into memory. The contents will be available as the second
// argument in the demonstration below, `contents`.
//-
file.download(function(err, contents) {});

//-
// Download a file to a local destination.
//-
file.download({
  destination: '/Users/vijayasrivuddanti/Downloads/download.txt'

}, function(err) {

    console.log("error",err);
});

//-
// If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.
//-
file.download().then(function(data) {
  const contents = data[0];
  console.log("entred");
  res.send("ok");
});
```

How to solve that error? Is there any way for downloading that file from cloud storage and how to get the stored file URL as response from cloud functions.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to download a file to a non-writable (and non-existent) folder in the Cloud Functions runtime.  There is no such folder as /Users.  That exists only on your own computer.  The only writable folder in Cloud Functions is `os.tmpdir()`, or /tmp.

Comment: But when we used /tmp we can't locate the file address .i used /tmp /download.txt. i am getting this error Error: The downloaded data did not match the data from the server. To be sure the content is the same, you should download the file again.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: if we used /tmp then we don't know where the /tmp directory created. am i correct?

Comment: can we get the stored file download url as response ?

Comment: Still don't know what you mean. /tmp is /tmp.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system

Comment: The writable folder in cloud functions is /tmp folder so the file will create in that folder. Can we see that folder and access it from the cloud functions for further use?

Comment: No, your code is not downloading to /tmp.  It telling the SDK to download to /Users/vijayasrivuddanti/Downloads/download.txt.  That's not at all the same. That looks like a path on your local machine.

Comment: i changed the path to /tmp. Where is /tmp folder located?

Comment: the `/tmp` path is located to on FIrebase's server that's running your instance of the cloud function. It is meant for when you need the server to make changes to a file... not for downloading to your desktop.


If you want to a Cloud Function to make changes to the `.txt` file then save it inside of the `/tmp` directory and make the changes and reupload it to firebase storage.

If you want to download a file from firebase storage to your computer, you have to use `.getSignedUrl()` method and it'll give you a download link.